# Ajax in ASP.NET MVC redirect to partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in ajax and ASP.NET MVC. When I click on button submit, I redirect to a partial page. I don't need redirect - I need replace div

Controller

```
public PartialViewResult ajaxtest(string prname)
{
    var aj = db.acount.Where(p => p.name.StartsWith(prname));
    return PartialView("_ajTest", aj.ToList());
}
```

View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ajaxtest", "Default1", new AjaxOptions () {
     HttpMethod = "POST",
     UpdateTargetId = "othmanN",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
}))
{
   <label>Product Name :</label>
   @Html.TextBox("prname")

   <input type="submit" name="name" value="search" />
}
<div id="othmanN">
//here table 
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried using JQuery , and just replace Html in success function ?

Comment: you can return partial view as string using this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730777/mvc-return-partial-view-as-json

Comment: i dont need convert to string

Comment: when it return as string you can use html string into html -replace div - $("container selector").html(returned html);

Comment: Did you include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` javascript file in your page ? If you are seeing a normal form submit instead of ajax, that means the needed scripts are not properly loaded. Check your browser console and see whether you are seeing any errors there.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212624/passing-updatetargetid-in-ajax-beginform-not-replacing-the-target/39212725#39212725

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, just need to import jquery.unobrusive-ajax.js

Import after jquery import

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

If you don't have de lib instaled, it's here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/

Comment: can you open chrome dev tools (f12) and check any errors in console please?